# Android App: Comfortable Reverse Image Search

Tags: android, images

I'm searching for an Android App which lets me **reverse search images** I have stored on my phone. It should:

- (optional)be able to work through the "share-menu" from Android - so if I'm in my Gallery application and click share I want to select the reverse search application
- it should let me **crop the image before searching**, I believe I might get better results if I can crop out the navigation bar + statusbar of my android device.
- display the results in its own browser or in my chrome browser - does not really matter
- Should utilize the Google search algorithm - it tends to get better results

I have tried reverse searching from the chrome browser but I think the process takes to many steps. Also I have tried Image Search from QiXingchen from the PlayStore which lets me utilize the share function but does not let me crop the images before searching.

Both free and paid apps are welcome if it suits my needs.

Maybe someone has a suggestion for me :) Happy to hear from you!

Comment: Have you tried to "share" it to the Google Search app? Just a guess – I cannot try this as I have no Google apps on my devices anymore :)

Comment: @Izzy thanks for your suggestion! The google app can't be used with the share menu as it seems. Have found another App and will add it as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for self-answering – good job! As your question (and answer) showed this section was completely missing from my lists: here's the new [image search](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_search#group_1061) section, in case you're still looking out for alternatives :)

Comment: @Izzy Awesome! Your list might come in handy in future :)

Comment: I shall hope so – that's what it's made for :) All hand-picked apps in real-life categories, should make it much easier to find apps for a given purpose. Many of those would most likely elude a direct search on Play Store. Not to forget the often linked additional resources like reviews & tutorials </ad> ;)

Comment: I like the web site Tineye.com, have used it for years and highly recommend it.IMO ir is better than Google (YMMV) They have an Android app in Beta - I doubt that it will let you crop the image, though; the web site certainly doesn't. hence, this is a comment, not an answer. See http://www.tineye.com/android/

Comment: @Mawg Thank you! Will check it out as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I finally found an App which fulfills all the requirements I have.

### [Search By An Image from Alexander K. Katiraie](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.searchbyanimage.app)

This app let's me

- use the share menu to search for pictures
- select pictures I want to reverse search from within the app
- crop the picture before searching
- uses it's own browser to show the results with the ability to open it in your default browser
- is a free app on the playstore

Seems to work really well for me so I would recommend it for others.

---

Note: I am not affiliated with this app or the developer.